# SVG circle element with "clip-path" and "drop-shadow" filer is giving ghosting effect in "Chrome" and "Edge" while drag and drop

Tags: google-chrome, svg, geometry, drag

Getting ghosting effect on drag of a SVG circle element, with "clip-path" and "drop-shadow" filer style, on chrome and edge browser. it's working fine in Firefox.

**Full example code in the jsfiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/SindhuraGanesh/3ebzusy2/9/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eBlP.png)

```
svg circle {
     stroke: #125a9b;
     stroke-width: 3px;
     -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 3px blue);
     -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 3px blue);
 }

// 1. Create paper, sets, and shapes

var paper = Raphael('SVG_DND_HOLDER_1', 500, 260);
var set = paper.set(),
    rect = paper.rect(10, 15, 64, 64, 5).attr({fill: 'pink'}),
    circle = paper.circle(150, 48, 32).attr({fill: 'lightblue'});

            var _svgNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
    var maxPointsRadi = 8;
    var clippath = document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'clipPath');
    clippath.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'pointClipPath');
    clippath.setAttributeNS(null, 'clipPathUnits','objectBoundingBox');
    paper.canvas.getElementsByTagName('defs')[0].appendChild(clippath);
        
    var rect = document.createElementNS(_svgNS, 'rect');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', (0 - maxPointsRadi));
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', (0 - maxPointsRadi));
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 500);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 260);
    clippath.appendChild(rect);
    circle.node.setAttribute("clip-path", 'url(#pointClipPath)');

// 2. Viola <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

set.push(rect, circle)         // populate the Set
   .draggable({margin: 10});   // Yes, that's it. Parameter is optional




// 3. Optional. You can stack more drag() event handlers of your own

var $debug = $('div#DEBUG'),
    move = function(dx, dy, mx, my, ev) {
        // Get mouse X/Y (relative to SVG/VML canvas)
        var offset = $(this.paper.canvas).parent().offset(),
            px = mx - offset.left,
            py = my - offset.top;

        $debug.html([
            'Drag Move: (Canvas offset relative to HTML doc): ' + 
                [offset.left, offset.top].join(', '),
            'Distance XY: ' + [dx, dy].join(', '),
            'Document XY: ' + [mx, my].join(', '),
            'Canvas XY: ' + [px, py].join(', ')
            ].join('<br>'));

    },
    start = function() { $debug.html('Drag Start'); },
    end = function() { $debug.html('Drag End'); };

set.drag(move, start, end);
```

When I drag circle element with 'clip-path' and 'drop-shadow' filter found ghosting effect at the background of the canvas in the path of drag in latest chrome and edge browser. It's working fine in Firefox. Expecting smooth drag with out any extra effects in chrome and edge.

Comment: you can report Chrome bugs [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: Are you sure, `clip-path` is needed - I can't see any clipping. Removing it seems to mitigate the effect.

Comment: yes, it is required in code of Graph-Builder